# how to tell how many parameter a FALSE subroutine take?

Tags: clojure

I am implementing a [FALSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FALSE) interpreter using Clojure , I'm stuck with how many parameters does a subroutine take, e.g.

```
[1+]
```

takes one parameter. On the other hand:

```
["hello"]
```

takes zero parameter

how to tell?

Comment: By examining the subroutine, presumably.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no need for parameters at all. You just need the stack present and work of that.

Comment: @Alxandr Yeah, the *parameter* I mean is the value on the stack, but we need to know how many stack frames to pop from the stack right?

Comment: No, you don't. There doesn't seem to be need of any framing, and as far as I can tell there are no exception-handling/casting either (only skimmed the language spec). Meaning that you only pop a value when you need to (inside the function).

Comment: Very good idea @Charles, I knew that would go [horribly wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2237018) and will remember this solution for the future :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After skimming the language-spec, this is how I would solve the problem.

Take the code `3[1+]!2`. I'm also using `|` as a separator on the stack.

First there is parsing into commands. This simple program would result in these 3 commands:

```
1. push 3
2. push [1+]
3. call
4. push 2
```

The easiest way to implement this (at least the easiest one I can think of atm) would be to have a array/list/stack-structure for the stack and a array/list/queue-structure for the commands. I'm going to try to illustrate how executing the following commands would result in changes in said two arrays.

```
Cmd                                    Stack
[push(3)|push([1+])|call|push(2)]      []
[push([1+])|call|push(2)]              [3]
[call|push(2)]                         [3|[1+]]
[push(1)|+|push(2)]                    [3]
[+|push(2)]                            [3|1]
[push(2)]                              [4]
[]                                     [4|2]
```

What `call` here does is this (expecting the program to be valid):

```
1. Pop the topmost stack-entry. (silently assume it to be a subrutine)
2. Parse the subrutine into a command array.
3. Iject said command array at the head of the executing command-array.
4. Continue execution until the command-array is empty.
```

The interesting thing about this is that you can't think of the subrutines as normal functions in OOP languages or similar. Imagine for instance the program `[1 2 3 4]!`. The subrutine would "return" 4 values while consuming 0.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my way of viewing the subroutine, now my  implementation is push all the subroute commands into the *main-stack* and execute the main-stack, so subroutine simply means insert some more commands into main-stack, so there is no need to know how many *parameters* any more.